# How to make a copy of an STL object stored in an array?

Tags: c++

There is something about STL objects and arrays that I clearly don't understand. Anytime (2 times) I try to store one in an array and later get it back something goes terribly wrong. Same code for a single object works fine.

```
 void other(){
      std::stringstream* streams[4];
      for(int i = 0; i < 4; i ++){
        streams[0] << "";
      }
    }


test2.cc:153:16: error: invalid operands of types 'std::stringstream* {aka std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>*}' and 'const char [1]' to binary 'operator<<'
     streams[0] << "";
```

Another example. Having array of queues retrieve a copy of each queue:

```
void debug(int num_workers, std::queue<int>* stuff){
      for(int i = 0; i < num_workers; i++){
        std::queue<int> q = stuff[i];
        printf("i:%d s:%d\n", i, stuff[i].size());
      }
    }
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
[2b7f97b93db8:07030] *** Process received signal ***
[2b7f97b93db8:07030] Signal: Aborted (6)
[2b7f97b93db8:07030] Signal code:  (-6)
[2b7f97b93db8:07030] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x12890)[0x7fa2b1040890]
[2b7f97b93db8:07030] [ 1] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0xc7)[0x7fa2b0c7be97]
[2b7f97b93db8:07030] [ 2] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x141)[0x7fa2b0c7d801]
[2b7f97b93db8:07030] [ 3] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0x8c957)[0x7fa2b14f1957]
[2b7f97b93db8:07030] [ 4] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0x92ab6)[0x7fa2b14f7ab6]
[2b7f97b93db8:07030] [ 5] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0x92af1)[0x7fa2b14f7af1]
[2b7f97b93db8:07030] [ 6] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0x92d24)[0x7fa2b14f7d24]
[2b7f97b93db8:07030] [ 7] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0x9329c)[0x7fa2b14f829c]
[2b7f97b93db8:07030] [ 8] tst(+0x71fe)[0x5579e1a411fe]
[2b7f97b93db8:07030] [ 9] tst(+0x6986)[0x5579e1a40986]
[2b7f97b93db8:07030] [10] tst(+0x5b2e)[0x5579e1a3fb2e]
[2b7f97b93db8:07030] [11] tst(+0x4bf2)[0x5579e1a3ebf2]
[2b7f97b93db8:07030] [12] tst(+0x3f81)[0x5579e1a3df81]
[2b7f97b93db8:07030] [13] tst(+0x36f7)[0x5579e1a3d6f7]
[2b7f97b93db8:07030] [14] tst(+0x33b7)[0x5579e1a3d3b7]
[2b7f97b93db8:07030] [15] tst(+0x1fef)[0x5579e1a3bfef]
[2b7f97b93db8:07030] [16] tst(+0x2738)[0x5579e1a3c738]
[2b7f97b93db8:07030] [17] tst(+0x28a5)[0x5579e1a3c8a5]
[2b7f97b93db8:07030] [18] tst(+0x2fa9)[0x5579e1a3cfa9]
[2b7f97b93db8:07030] [19] tst(+0x482f)[0x5579e1a3e82f]
[2b7f97b93db8:07030] [20] tst(+0x3bbc)[0x5579e1a3dbbc]
[2b7f97b93db8:07030] [21] tst(+0x7f98)[0x5579e1a41f98]
[2b7f97b93db8:07030] [22] tst(+0x7f54)[0x5579e1a41f54]
[2b7f97b93db8:07030] [23] tst(+0x7f24)[0x5579e1a41f24]
[2b7f97b93db8:07030] [24] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0xbd66f)[0x7fa2b152266f]
[2b7f97b93db8:07030] [25] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x76db)[0x7fa2b10356db]
[2b7f97b93db8:07030] [26] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x3f)[0x7fa2b0d5e88f]
[2b7f97b93db8:07030] *** End of error message ***
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that process rank 7 with PID 0 on node 2b7f97b93db8 exited on signal 6 (Aborted).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: @TedLyngmo I removed it as irrelevant

Comment: Ok. The `*` in `std::stringstream* streams[4];` makes you create 4 uninitialized pointers to `std::stringstream`s instead of 4 `std::stringstream`s as ShadowRanger answered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You didn't declare an array of `std::stringstream`, you declared an array of *pointers* to `std::stringstream`. And neither made them point to anything useful, nor dereferenced them when you used them. You code should work just fine if:

```
std::stringstream* streams[4];
```

was changed to:

```
std::stringstream streams[4];
```

In your second example, `std::bad_alloc` was thrown indicating a failure to allocate memory. The code here appears to be fine (assuming you pass valid arguments), but odds are you have other code that either filled or corrupted your heap, and/or you passed a garbage pointer to the function (you aren't super careful about initializing arrays and pointers, and it always bites you eventually) and it's only noticed when another allocation is requested and everything blows up.